# При выборке в JSON_OBJECT` с переменной в WHERE клаузе ошибка: ORA-00904: invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle19c

Пытаюсь создать несколько срезов записей из таблицы, используя `JSON_OBJECT`. Но, кажется, что нельзя использовать переменную в `WHERE` клаузе.

Упрощённый воспроизводимый пример того, что делаю:

```
CREATE TABLE SAMPLE(
  person_id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  first_name VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
  last_name VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO SAMPLE (person_id, first_name, last_name)
  VALUES (1, 'John', 'Doe');
INSERT INTO SAMPLE (person_id, first_name, last_name)
  VALUES (2, 'Mary', 'Doe');

DECLARE
  name VARCHAR2(50) := 'John';   
  jsonResult CLOB;
BEGIN
  SELECT JSON_OBJECT(*)
  INTO jsonResult
  FROM SAMPLE
  WHERE first_name = name;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(jsonResult);
END;
/
```

Получаю ошибку, что переменная `name` неизвестна:

> Error report -
> ORA-00904: "NAME": invalid identifier
> ORA-06512: at line 5

Как можно исправить?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How to use a where clause with Oracle JSON_OBJECT](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67729637) от участника [@pabloelustondo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1173878/pabloelustondo)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/67729637

Answer (score 3):

Начиная с версии 19c синтаксис для [JSON_OBJECT](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/JSON_OBJECT.html#GUID-1EF347AE-7FDA-4B41-AFE0-DD5A49E8B370) был упрощён и стало возможным использовать шаблон `*` в листе инициализации.

В данном случае, скорее всего, имеет место новый баг. Попытки обойти его пока не увенчались успехом (см. на [LiveSQL 19.8](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/luokngi7pdslssn5s9kbdq210)).

Единственная пока возможность, не использовать шаблон `*` и указывать все колонки явно:

```
declare 
    name varchar2(50) := 'John';    
    jsonResult clob; 
begin 
    select json_object (person_id, first_name, last_name) into jsonResult 
    from sample 
    where first_name = name; 
    dbms_output.put_line (jsonResult); 
end; 
/
```

> {"PERSON_ID":1,"FIRST_NAME":"John","LAST_NAME":"Doe"}

Answer (score 0):

Версия oracle 19c. Мне помогло использование execute immediate. Т.е. пример автора можно переписать так:

```
  execute immediate 'SELECT JSON_OBJECT(*) FROM SAMPLE WHERE first_name = :name'
  into jsonResult using name;
```

В данном случае ошибки нет.